# Remote access of Stratos Account Manager from IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I need to be able to update the tenant account information from Identity Server without having to login to the `Apache Stratos Manager`. I intend to do this via a custom jsp page.

1. How can this be done?
2. What jars need to be added to IS?
3. What method calls to perform the calls?

I have tried to copy the `account-mgr.jsp` code but fail to access the `AccountMgrService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the following `jar`s from `Manager` to `IS`,

```
|-- org.wso2.carbon.account.mgt-1.5.2.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.account.mgt.stub-3.2.2.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.account.mgt.ui-1.5.2.jar
|-- drools-5.0.1.wso2v1.jar
|-- jsr94-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.billing.core-1.5.2.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.billing.mgt-1.5.2.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.email.sender-1.5.2.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.email.verification-3.2.1.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.adapters-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rulecep.commons-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rule.core-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rule.engine.drools-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rule.engine.jsr94-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.rule.server-3.2.0.jar
|-- org.wso2.carbon.usage-1.5.2.jar
`-- org.wso2.carbon.usage.meteringqueryds.stub-3.2.0.jar
```

Also copy `billing-config.xml` from `$MANAGER_HOME/repository/conf` to `$IS_HOME/repository/conf` directory.

Ideally it should only require `account.mgt.*.jar`s, but since account management depends on billing and so on you will need all the above mention `jar`s in you `classpath`. This is as of the latest WSO2 Stratos release version 1.5.2.

We are looking into making account management independent from billing.

Comment: This method does cause to appear in the menu the following link configure-account . However, log file shows the following                                                                   [WSO2 Stratos Identity] ERROR org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getCustomerWithName {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.billing.mgt.services.BillingDataAccessService.getCustomerWithName(BillingDataAccessService.java:39)

Comment: Okay, this works. My problem was that my billing-config.xml had an incorrect parameter. I corrected it and now I am able to get this to work.

Comment: Just as a side note: I had to add org.wso2.carbon.register.ui-1.5.1.jar and org.wso2.carbon.tenant.register.stub-3.2.0.jar also before I could do an update on the form. I may only need one of those but to be safe I put both.